# How do I translate contact component in Joomla with Falang?

Tags: joomla

I've implemented falang on my site which works great. However, I can't find a way to translate the name of my contacts.

I'm using the menu item type 'Single Contact' for my 'Get in touch' menu item. This displays a contact form when clicked with the contact name at the top like a page title. I've named my contact 'Get in touch' so it looks like a standard page title, but need this to be 'Ons Bereiken' in Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Dutch language pack?

For 2.5+ the easiest thing is to go to the language manager and create an override for the string (on the overrides tab).